# How does a lead screw affect the torque of a motor? Can a leadscrew be used as way of increasing torque?

Tags: torque

I'm planning on using a lead screw for my robotic arm project. My question was that if I for example use a 3Nm torque motor and couple it to a lead screw (four-start lead screw), does the torque remain the same? Or does it increase?

How do I calculate the torque that the lead screw will give out? I know that a lead screw converts rotary motion into linear motion.

[image: Lead Screw Driven Robot Arm]

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Torque is torque. If the leadscrew is coupled directly to the motor it will still be 3 Nm. 
Do you mean axial force the lead screw will provide (linear force)? The lead screw (and nut) converts your torque into axial force.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes I believe I am talking about the linear force my bad. From the diagram I have added to the question, my question is that will the motor that is driving the lead screw still need a torque of 10Nm?

Comment: It's called a worm gear.

Comment: @jko, torque is not torque.  Power works this way, but torque is affected by simple machines like screws or gears.

Comment: @TigerGuy yes but if it's coupled directly to the motor it will have the same torque

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is all just leverage, mechanical advantage. You can solve all of it through ratio of movements on each side.

Assuming 3 N/m and screw advances about 8 mm per 1 turn and its radius is 4 mm.

Forst find linear force, tangential at screw's side in this case

3 N/m / 0.004 m

Gives 750 N at the screw's side, tangential. To get axial force, find ratio of movement:

750 / ( 0.004 * 2 * 3.14) * 0.008

Gives 239 N axial force of the screw. Then you also draw another lever at your arm, but it ratio of shoulders is close to 1, so it can be ignored. If it is far from 1:1, calculate it too. If hand part is 3 times as long as the muscle part, then you get 80 N at the hand part.

And yes, worm gear or screw drive give large mechanical advantage that is used for making slow and strong movements.

Comment: @user36991 its a typo, i've fixed it

Comment: Ah ok thanks!!!, so basically the 3Nm torque from the motor (rotational motion) is converted into 239N axial force (linear motion. Is that correct?

Comment: @user36991 yes. For the sizes I mentioned

Comment: Ok great, also how do I calculate the axial force that I will be needing for my arm. Is it all the mass*gravity for each of the masses on that link?

Comment: @user36991 force * length should be equal on both sides of the lever

Comment: @Suprised Seagull, so if the force*length is equal on both sides. Would that mean any amount of torque motor will be able to allow the lead screw to move the arm up and down?

Comment: @user36991 Yes. Given large enough leverage, tou can move the earth

Comment: @SuprisedSeagull That's Great!! I thought I will need a huge motor. But a small NEMA 17 for example should be enough then I'm guessing.

Comment: @user36991 still, calculate it. Leverage can be impractical

Comment: @SurpisedSeagull How do I calculate, I know how to calculate the axial force given out by the lead screw from your answer above. How do I calculate the torque that my motor will need? I only know the torque needed at the shoulder joint.

Comment: @user36991 axial force at the screw * shoulder length at the motor side = shoulder length at the tool side * load

Comment: @Suprised Seagull So I would make axial force at the screw the subject. And axial force at the screw is the force that I need my lead screw to output. Is this correct? (I updated the image from my initial question in more detail).

Comment: @user36991 yes.

Comment: Do I not need to consider any of the masses? So, the calculations from the formula would be, AXIAL FORCE AT THE SCREW = (0.9m*0.1kg)/0.3m= 0.3N? Sorry about making this discussion so long, I appreciate the help a lot!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134329/discussion-between-user36991-and-surprised-seagull).